# Associating Event Receiver with Multiple Lists

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, event-receivers

How can I add single event receiver to multiple Lists?

Comment: Is it for a particular list type or "random" lists in your site ?

Answer (score 0):

You can have one content type that is used in all lists and then attach the event receiver to this content type. This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the Elements.xml schema, you can have multiple Receivers elements. The receivers element have a property "ListUrl" that you can use to bind your receiver.

```
<Elements>
  <Receivers
     ListUrl="lists/yourlist">
     <Receiver>
         <Receiver>
           ...
           <Assembly>assemblydef</Assembly>
           <Class>classdef</Class>
           ...
         <Receiver/>
     <Receiver/>
  </Receivers>
  <Receivers
      ListUrl="lists/yourlist2">
      <Receiver>
        ...
        <Assembly>assemblydef</Assembly>
        <Class>classdef</Class>
        ...
      <Receiver/>
   </Receivers>
</Elements>
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is:

1) Create a content type

2) Attach the "content type" to one or more lists

3) Associate the event to "content type" programmatically

Sample code to point 1:

```
public static void agregarEventoTipoContenido(string clase, SPContentType tipoContenido, string ensamblado, SPEventReceiverType eventReceiverType, SPEventReceiverSynchronization sincro)
        {
            SPEventReceiverDefinition eventReceiver = tipoContenido.EventReceivers.Add();
            eventReceiver.Synchronization = sincro;
            eventReceiver.Type = eventReceiverType;
            eventReceiver.Assembly = ensamblado;
            eventReceiver.Class = clase;
            eventReceiver.HostType = SPEventHostType.ContentType;
            eventReceiver.Update();
        }
```